# Unable to use pytorch pretrained vision models in extended architecture

Tags: pytorch, resnet

i am trying to implement a paper and the first step is to have an image feature extractor ( that will need to be trained along with other components)..post that i need to pass the features from this to the next leg (which is a transformer encoder)..oh and also, i am new to pytorch ( mostly use keras and TF ) ..so please let me know what i am doing wrong. I am getting an error "Pass execution failedLLVM ERROR: Failed to translate..." ..pfb the code

```
class VisionLLM(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, config):
    super().__init__()
    assert config.vocab_size is not None
    assert config.block_size is not None
    self.config = config
    print('OUT HERE VOCAB SZ = ', config )
    self.image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50")

    self.image_feat_backbone_ = models.resnet50( pretrained=True )
    self.image_feat_backbone_ = self.image_feat_backbone_.to('cuda')
    ## query encoding will be used both for
    # self.language_guided_image_encoder &
    # self.transformer_decoder
    ## since both require language tokens as inputs
    self.bert_query_encoder = config.text_pretrained_model

    self.language_guided_image_encoder = nn.ModuleDict(dict(
        wte = nn.Embedding(config.vocab_size, config.n_embd),
        wpe = nn.Embedding(config.block_size, config.n_embd),

        drop = nn.Dropout(config.dropout),
        h = nn.ModuleList([Cross_attn_Block(config) for _ in range(config.n_layer)]),
        ln_f = LayerNorm(config.n_embd, bias=config.bias),
    ))

    self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=512, nhead=8)


def forward( self, img_, text_inp_enc, text_inp_dec ,targets_=None ):
    device = img_.device

    #inputs = self.image_processor( img_, return_tensors="pt")

    ## get the image features !
    #print( 'Abt to begin->', inputs )
    print( 'Abt to begin->', img_.size() )

    op_vision_feats_ = self.image_feat_backbone_( img_ )
```

This is where i get the error ..when i try calling the model with an img ..the input size of the image is per spec -> Batch_sz, 3, 224, 224 .. i should add that i am NOT using any torch classes to preprocess the image .. i have already pre processed a few images for test using opencv ..any pointers to what could possibly be wrong will be deeply appreciated